# Making a password verification into a class

Tags: java

I have a program grabbing a password from the user, then it checks if the conditions are met or not then outputs "Valid Password" or "Invalid Password". This works, and I was able to turn the verification aspect into a method in the same program and it works, but I want to make it into a class where I can just say `if( validate(pw) == true ) ...` or at least `if( v.getValidation() == true ) ...` in any program and it will test my conditions. I've used custom classes before but for some reason everything I try does not work on this one, I've been at it for days.

Here's my method:

```
public boolean validate( String pw )
{
   boolean l = false, u = false, lo = false, d = false, r = true;

   if( pw.length() >= 6 )
     { l = true; }      

   for( int i = 0; i < pw.length(); i++ )
   {
      if( Character.isUpperCase( pw.charAt(i) ) )
       { u = true; }

      if( Character.isLowerCase( pw.charAt(i) ) )
       { lo = true; }

      if( Character.isDigit( pw.charAt(i) ) )
       { d = true; }
   }

   if( l == false || u == false || lo == false || d == false )
     { r = false; }

   return r;
}
```

Edit:

Thank you all for your input, this is what it came out to in the end:

```
public class Password
{
   public static boolean validate( String pw )
   {
      boolean result = false;
      int upper = 0, lower = 0, digit = 0;

      if( pw.length() >= 6 )
      {
         for( int i = 0; i < pw.length(); i++ )
         {
            if( Character.isUpperCase( pw.charAt(i) ) )
              { upper++; }

            if( Character.isLowerCase( pw.charAt(i) ) )
              { lower++; }

            if( Character.isDigit( pw.charAt(i) ) )
              { digit++; }
         }
      }

      if( upper >= 1 && lower >= 1 && digit >= 1 )
        { result = true; }

      return result;
   }
}
```

Comment: If the length is less than 6 you can just return false. No need to check the characters.

Comment: Yeah... I could skip having a variable for length and just make the for loop dependent on a length in an if. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to make a whole class for this. You can do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean valid = validate("PassWord22");
}
public static boolean validate( String pw ) {}
```

---

Also some notes on your method:

- You don't need to do `l == true` or `l == false` in your if statement. You can simply do:

  ```
  if( !l || !u || !lo || !d )
  { r = false; }
  ```

  In fact you can just return

  ```
  return l && u && lo && d;
  ```
- If the length is not 6 or greater, simply return false. This will save checking all the letters in the `String`
- I would come up with better variable names. Single/two letter variable names makes it very hard to tell what they represent, and easy to mix up. (instead of `l` you could have `length` and instead of `u` you could have `upper`)

Also this can be easier solved with regex and [`String.matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)):

```
public static boolean validate(String pw) {
    String pattern = "^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).+$";
    return (pw.length() > 5 && pw.matches(pattern));
}
```

Comment: First part: Does not meet specifications. 
Second part: Thank you, I didn't know `if` will assume true with just the variable and no ! and false with ! at start of the variable. I don't know how it's possible that `return !l || !u || !lo || !d;` will work though, isn't that saying result will just be equivalent to one or the other of those? (shrugs) But what do I know. 
Part 3: Yeah someone mentioned that in a comment on the Q, it makes sense.
Part 4: They seemed obvious to me but I'll take your word for it and change them. 
Part 5: My class hasn't covered that yet x.x

Comment: @PålHart May I ask how the first part does not meet the specifications? And yeah I had a type on that. It should be `return l && u && lo && d;`. And yes it may be obvious at the moment, and in such a small program. But when you come back to your code late it'll be much harder to determine what they are meant to be. Writing descriptive variable names is a good practice to get into.

Comment: It did not meet specifications because the question was how to make it work as a separate class. I said in the original post that it already worked as a method within the same program so that answer wasn't giving anything toward the question. Ultimately my issue was that I was trying to force it to be a "formal" class because that's how my teacher taught me to do it, when an "informal" class was far more appropriate in this case.

Comment: For the record, I still think the single letter variables are obvious weeks later but meh. There's a lot of "good practice" organization techniques and stuff my teacher taught me that I also don't understand the point of, if you know the programming language isn't it obvious what it's doing based on the code regardless of the formatting? I can look at a code in a language I don't even know and figure out the logic just by reading it, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: @PålHart Yes in a simple program like this it might be obvious, but in more complex ones it can become a problem. Also you are not the only person who will be looking at/trying to understand/modify your code, and the other people who look at your code will find it very helpful to have descriptive variable names

Answer (score -1):

I got it working, turned out to be an error in the code that the compiler was not picking up. I wanted to delete the question but they wont let me for some reason. So in case you're curious this is what my class looks like functioning:

```
public class Password
{
   private String pw;

   public Password()
   {
      pw = "";
   }

   public Password( String pw )
   {
      this.pw = pw;
   }

   public boolean getPassword( String pw )
   {
      boolean l = false, u = false, lo = false, d = false, r = true;

      if( pw.length() >= 6 )
        { l = true; }      

      for( int i = 0; i < pw.length(); i++ )
      {
         if( Character.isUpperCase( pw.charAt(i) ) )
           { u = true; }

         if( Character.isLowerCase( pw.charAt(i) ) )
           { lo = true; }

         if( Character.isDigit( pw.charAt(i) ) )
           { d = true; }
      }

      if( l == false || u == false || lo == false || d == false )
        { r = false; }

      return r;
   }
```